# Where should the files go in a SharePoint solution?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, organization

Our SharePoint solution has recently been upgraded to SharePoint 2010, and we are taking a look at how we package and deploy the site to see if there are better ways to do things.

We currently package all files needed for our site (dll's, images, svc files, xap files, js files, css files, masterpages, html files, aspx files) and deploy them to 14/template/features/OurFeature/

I've been doing a lot of reading about [SharePoint Developer Tools in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff872401.aspx), and I would like to use this to package/deploy our solution.  It seems Visual Studio allows for mapped folders to SharePoint's images and layouts directories, and also allows other mapped folders.  I'm wondering if there are standard locations for any of the other file types that I have mentioned above, or is our current method of storing things in the template/features folder a good idea?  We currently map things to this folder in IIS, so ~/images/ points to our site's images and so forth.

Can someone point me to best practices for SharePoint site file organization?  Are there benefits to doing things one way versus another?

Comment: I wasn't very clear above.  We currently put dll's in the site's bin folder, not the GAC and not in the FEATURE folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Images should go in `14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES` or an Image Library (I usually use an image library so images can be changed without forcing a deployment).
- Client Libraries (.xap files, .js files, etc.) should go in `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin`
- .dll files should get sent to the `GAC` or the `BIN` directory for the web application running the assembly
- .css files can live in a document library, ClientBin, a custom folder under `14\TEMPLATE\Layouts`, or `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\STYLES`  (I usually put these in a style library so they can be changed if needed without having to re-deploy the whole solution.)
- .svc files should go in `14\ISAPI`.  These are accessed under the `/_vti_bin/` path.
- Features go in `14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES`

Comment: Is there a benefit to putting files in these locations instead of all in a directory under TEMPLATE\FEATURES?  We currently do that, and map virtual folders in IIS to allow for easy access.

Comment: You don't need to map a directory to do this for you.  Anything under `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` Can be accessed via the browser under `/_layouts/` (images too, even though that path isn't under the `LAYOUTS` directory.  SharePoint allows you to access these directories from anywhere in your site structure (for example: `http://sitecollection/_layouts` and `http://sitecollection/site1/site2/_layouts` both point to the same location on disk).  A lot of the application pages rely on this to determine the site to operate on (create a new list and look at the url for an example)

Comment: Also, its Microsoft's best practice to use the locations I list above.

Comment: I just went to a Microsoft training, and the trainer informed me that images go in images, pages go in layouts, and everything else should go in a folder in features.

Comment: I added some flash files as resources to my web part and deployed it.
The flash files went into "14\TEMPLATES\FEATURES\MyWebPart", how do I access them from a URL?  I can't seem to find anything about "_features/mywebpart" or other references?

Comment: @Paige you won't be able to access files in the FEATURES directory via the URL by default (Dana appears to be doing some kind of custom IIS folder mapping to expose files in the FEATURES directory via a url).  I recommend putting flash files in the ClientBin directory that I mention above.

Comment: What if you wanted to download jQuery to use in your solution?  The downloadable content is a combination of .js and .css with an images folder.  I just kept all jQuery .css and images together in the Layouts/Styles with the image subfolder in there.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Kyle said, if you put files in the hive (14), say in Images, Layouts, Styles, it is normally good practice to add a directory (shortened namespace) to avoid name clashes.